# Javascript timer for different DOM events in single setInterval method

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am using setInterval to update 3 charts for 60 sec time of interval. So I created a global variable i.e. "Updatetimer" and called 3 charts seperately at the time of rendering of elements. So Now, My Charts are being updating in every 60 seconds(this is for "30mins" data).

So far this is good.

Now problem is coming when I am clicking one of the charts to render for different Time i.e for "24hrs" data. So what should happen is Updatetimer should update the data for 24hrs" data for 1st chart and continue on updating "30 mins" data for other two charts.   but as I have calling all charts using single variable i.e. "UpdateTimer" On clearing "UpdateTimer" and calling setInterval for clicked event is simply fetching data for on 1st chart "30mins" data.

I tried to solve this by creating three different Timers for 3 charts and by running setInterval on them seperately, but this would update charts at different Time Interval and will make calls every now and then.

I want to come up with a solution where I can setInterval on charts at init and set the Interval on charts using single variable and when the is an event clicked on the DOM let say "24hrs" data of first chart is clicked. I want to set the update timer on the 1st chart without affecting other charts timer.

```
// Demo Code
function init() {
updatetimer = setInterval(function() { function A_30min(); function B_30min(); function C_30min() },60000);
}

events: {
 "click .A_24" : "A_24hr"    //lets say class selector is .A_24

}

function A_30min() { //statement// }
function A_24hr() { 
 clearInterval(updatetimer);
 setInterval(A_24hr, 60000);  
}
function B_30min() { //statement// }
function B_24hr() { //statement// }
function C_30min() { //statement// }
function C_24hr() { //statement// }
```

Any help would be welcome, Thanks

Comment: No Actually what I want to do is that at the click event on "24hr" of 1st Chart, the chart should update data for 1st chart with 24hr data and continue running "30min" data for other two charts. This way all charts keep on updating data under single setInterval call

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, but this would make request for each chart in different interval and all charts would be loading on different timers which wont look good to the user. Isnt it?

Comment: ok, Do you have any other solution other than making 3 different Intervals? As I dont want chart to load on different timer as User will be able to see the latence in chart rendering at diffeerent Inteval

Comment: No Actually all 3 charts have each "30min" and "24hr" data . So Its upto user to select any charts data he wants. lets say if he selects "24hr" data of second data, so this time 1st wil show "30min" data and2nd one will show "24hr" data  and 3rd will show "30min" data in every 60 sec. if user then select "24hr data " of 1st one  so this will show "24 hr" data for 1st one and rest will show as pervius changes.

Comment: Do you get it what I am saying now? Pl. let me know

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused.  I was under the assumption that 30 minutes and 24 hours were the intervals you wanted to wait to check on.  But are you saying that they always execute every 60 seconds, and just the selection changes what is displayed?

Comment: yes thats what I am saying, selection on different events will fetch different chart data but wont affect other chart

Comment: Then that's completely different, :).  What I would suggest in that case is to use a data element ( https://api.jquery.com/data ) on the charts, set them to the 30 or 24 or whatever to know what data to show, and in your interval when you get the data for each chart, check it's data field to know what you need to get

Comment: ok Thank you very much. Willl use data elements as per your suggestion. But one question though will I be able to bind these data element in single Interval call. I am not much familier about data element

Comment: You won't change them in the interval, just check them.  They will be set (I assume) on init() when the 30 interval starts, and change them when the user makes the different selection.  All the interval has to do is grab the value for the chart it's trying to update at a time, and use it

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an Answer other than using suggested data element of jquery.

What I did is created 3 global variable those are initializing with default events or property. Now when the page loads and renders the elements on DOM and lets say User clicked on any events on charts (suppose he/she clicked on 24hrs on chart1) So what I am doing is getting the click event from that event trigger and checking the triggered event with my global variable. So If my global variable is different than the click event, Global variable will change to the new click event triggered.

Now I am calling my functions based using setInterval and when functions are called it will check with the with new current clicked item, if it is clicked event it will call those API's otherwise Default one will be called.

```
Demo:

function init() {
this.current_selected_chartA = "A_30";
this.current_selected_chartB = "B_30";
this.current_selected_chartC = "C_30";
updatetimer = setInterval(function() { function A_30min(); function B_30min(); 
function C_30min() },60000);
}
events: {
"click .A_24, .A_30, .B_24, .B_30, .C_24, .C_30" : "clickEvent"    //lets say user selects any of these selectors
}

clickEvent: function(event) {
if(event.currentTarget.attributes.name.value == "A_24") {
this.current_selected_chartA = "A_24";
this.A(); 
this.B();
this.C();
setInterval(function() { this.A();this.B();this.C();},60000);
} 
else { 
//statement// 
} // same if condition will check current selected events for other events like A_30, B_30, B_24, C_30,and C_24.

function A() { //statement//
 if(this.current_selected_chartA == "A_30"){
 // callA_30 API's
 }
 else {
 // callA_24 API's
 } 
}
function B() { //similar if else condition will follow for function B// }
function C() { //similar if else condition will follow for function B// }
```